# ecryptfs ecryptfs-add-passphrase and mount issues

Tags: mount, ecryptfs

I'm using ecryptfs for a folder not within my home directory. The authentication is passphrase only. If I mount the folder with the ecryptfs mount-helper all is working fine.

If I then unmount the folder and mount it again not using the mount-helper (`-i` option), the folder is mounted again with no issue.

Then I reboot the machine and add a key to the key-ring with `ecryptfs-add-passphrase`. After this I try to mount again without the mount-helper but this will not work.

This is my mount command:

```
mount -i -t ecryptfs -o "ecryptfs_sig....." /mnt/crypt_folder /mnt/crypt_folder
```